# Template changes after installing django-allauth?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am trying to install [Django-rest-auth + registration](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). In the docs, it says to install Django-allauth which I did following the steps found [here](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). However, once I did and migrated, my app seemed to be using a different template than the one I had set up originally.

I am using Django Rest Framework and Angular JS.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    # Django Rest Framework
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    # All auth
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    # Rest auth
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',

    # My app
    'myapp',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1
```

My **urls.py** in my project folder looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # My api url
    url(r'^api/', include('myapp.urls')),

    # My application url
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html')),
    # all auth Url
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    # Rest-auth url
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

Before installing the all-auth app, going to 127.0.0.1:8000 returned a page using the base.html file. However, now I get a page with the following things:

Menu:

- Link to Change E-mail
- Sign out

What am I doing wrong? and how do I fix the problem. Thanks.
Any help is greatly appreciated!